# Optimal way for letting user download big files in the server using Django

Tags: django, download, background

I am making a Django application for an experiment and it will offer the possibility to the user to be able to download really big image files to a specific directory **in the server**.

I have a PoC of that working, where the user sees a button clicks on it and the process to download begins. I have put the download process inside `views.py` which means it occurs upon visiting a specified URL.

The code responsible for the download part similar to the following:

```
with open(loc, "wb") as f:
    response = s.get(pos, stream=True)
    total_length = response.headers.get('content-length')
    if total_length is None:
        f.write(response.content)
    else:
        dl = 0
        total_length = int(total_length)
        for data in response.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
            dl += len(data)
            f.write(data)
```

The problem is that for some images which are > 500MB the process takes quite some time and there are several issues, like if the user closes the app, or clicks away then the process stops.

How can I make it in such a way so the user visits that page and clicks that button and the download process begins on the background without binding the user to stay to that page.

Also maybe creating another endpoint which could update the user about the status of the download process.

Please feel free to share any ideas or thoughts.

Comment: If you were hosting files of > 500 mb size, I would suggest looking into filestorage such as Amazon S3. You could supply the user with a download link to that file so it can download it anytime the user requests it and it probably saves you hosting costs.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion -- the user does NOT download the file to his personal space. The files need to be downloaded in the server so they are processed at a later stage.

Comment: Have you looked into [async](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/async/)?